# DynamoDB result is not structured the way I want

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am doing a simple command to list all the items in my table. However, the data I am getting back is not structured the way I want. I want a simple JSON structure but DynamoDB is turning the results into nested objects.

DynamoDB gives me below response:

```json
// What I am currently getting
[
  {
    id: { S: '8' },
    lastName: { S: 'Perry' },
    firstName: { S: 'Matthew' }
  },
  {
    id: { S: '3' },
    firstName: { S: 'Joan' },
    lastName: { S: 'Peter' }
  }
]
```

But I want this:

```json
// What I want
[
  {
    id: 8
    lastName:  'Perry' ,
    firstName: 'Matthew' 
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Joan' ,
    lastName:  'Peter' 
  }
]
```

How can I achieve the later result set. Below is my code:

```js
const { ExecuteStatementCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb') 
const { ddbDocClient, memberTableName } = require('./client.js')

const selectAll = async () => {
    const params = {
        Statement: `SELECT * FROM ${memberTableName}`,
        Parameters: [{ S: '3' }]
    }
    console.log(params)
    return await ddbDocClient.send(new ExecuteStatementCommand(params));
}


selectAll()
.then(d => console.log(d.Items))
```

ddbDocClient was created like this:

```js
 const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(ddbClient);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command import is incorrect.  To send and receive native JS types, import the `ExecuteStatementCommand` command from the  [@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_dynamodb.html) "document client" package.

```js
const { ExecuteStatementCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb');
```

You are importing the command from the "regular client" package [@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/index.html), i.e. the one that accepts and returns DynamoDB JSON.

Note:  The `Parameters: [{ S: '3' }]` line is also wrong, but it's currently not causing trouble because your statement is scanning for all records.  If you were to include a `WHERE id=?` phrase in the statement, make sure to change the parameters to `Parameters: ['3']`.  You must pass JS types to the "document client" commands.

Comment: Thanks but I've given up on the whole dynamo thing (plus the entire serverless stack). Too much of a headache!

Answer (score 0):

You need use simple lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb

then use like this:

```js
const { DynamoDB } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { marshall, unmarshall } = require("@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb");

const client = new DynamoDB(clientParams);
const params = {
  TableName: "Table",
  Key: marshall({
    HashKey: "hashKey",
  }),
};

const { Item } = await client.getItem(params);
unmarshall(Item);
```